# Calculate the flux of the following surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the surface inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and on the plane $y+z=2$, and the vector field $F= \langle y,x,z^2\rangle$. I don't know how to find the flux of this surface. I know how to do flux, I just don't know how to set up the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface is a piece of the plane $z=2-y$, so it is a graph. So you can parameterize the surface as $\vec{r}(x,y) = \left<x,y,2-y\right>$ over the region $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.

Another possibility is to use cylindrical coordinates (because of the region $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$). It'll be the same as above, but plugging in $x \to r\cos(\theta)$ and $y \to r\sin(\theta)$. So you'd parameterize the surface as

$$ \vec{r}(r,\theta) = \left< r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), 2 - r\sin(\theta) \right> $$

This way the bounds on the integral will be $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Since you say you know how to compute flux, you should be able to do the rest from here, right?

Comment: Awesome. That is just what I needed!

Comment: How is the normal of this parameterization? How would the normal look graphically?